# How often does Miranium and Revenue tick?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

There doesn't seem to be a discernible pattern to how often you get Miranium and credits from mining/research probes. Additionally, they seem to go at different intervals - sometimes mining will trigger, sometimes the money will trigger, and sometimes the rare materials will trigger. Is there a pattern or timer to this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like Revenue ticks every 30 minutes, Miranium ticks every 45 minutes, and items tick every 15 minutes. This would explain them sometimes overlapping, and sometimes not.

Comment: According to this thread, seems like there's some anti-idle functionality that may prevent ticks from happening: https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/701151-xenoblade-chronicles-x/72951245

Comment: @RahatAhmed This is correct. It seems as though you can only leave the game run for a max of one hour unattended. I heard someone worked around this by using a fan to keep the gyro on the gamepad constantly in motion, which let them idle indefinitely. Fortunately when you beat the game, idling is no longer necessary.